# can primitive tag react three fiber only be used once for the same model

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have an iphone model and i want to load it to my react project. I use primitive tag from react three fiber R3F which is not a real object that we will be able to see in the scene, but it’s a container supported by R3F. I want to display 2 iphone that'w why i use primitive tag twice for the same model but the first primitive tag doesn't load the model and only the second one. Is is because i only can use it once for the same model? Should i copy the model and

```
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls, useHelper, useScroll, Html } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useRef, forwardRef } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    const model = useGLTF('/iphone_14_pro_max.glb');
    const model2 = useGLTF('/iphone_14_pro_max.glb');

    const scroll = useScroll()

    const iphone = useRef()
    const first = useRef()

    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        //kapan pake range kapan pake visible?
        const r1 = scroll.range(0 / 4, 1 / 4)
        const r2 = scroll.range(1 / 4, 1 / 4)
        const r3 = scroll.range(1 / 4, 1 / 4)

        iphone.current.rotation.y = (Math.PI * 0.67) + r1 + r2 + r3 * 3

    })

    return(
        <>
            <directionalLight position={ [ 1, 2, 3 ] } intensity={ 1.5 } />
            <ambientLight intensity={ 0.5 } />

            <primitive ref={iphone} object={model.scene} scale={20} position={ [ 0, -1.5, 0] }>
                <Tagline ref={first} left="PRO" right="BEYOND"></Tagline>
            </primitive>

            <primitive object={model2.scene} scale={15} position={ [ 1, 1, 1] } rotation-y={-45}/> 
        </>
    )
}

const Tagline = forwardRef(({ left, right, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Html occlude ref={ref} className="homepage" center {...props}>
        <h1>{left}</h1>
        <h1>{right}</h1>
      </Html>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have an answer that `primitive` tag can only load one model for each tag. If you want to load the same model then you need to copy it with different name and load it agaian.